# My variable is not giving its value in the url of of WhoIs Lookup API

Tags: php, api

I want to create an iplookup search in my website, but whenever I pass my variable it shows variable undefined, or the api gives error of domain not passed. I dont know what is going wrong, some help would be appreciated!!

```
    <?php 
  include 'includes/header.php';
?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h1 style="font-weight:600;">IP LOOKUP</h1>
      <form action="ip_lookup.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="IP" placeholder="Enter IP">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['IP'])){
      $got = $_POST['IP'];
    }
  }
   $ip_look = file_get_contents("https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?apiKey=****&domainName=".$got."");
     var_dump($ip_look);
  ?>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Output:: string(157) " WHOIS_01 "got" is an invalid domain name "**

Comment: You forgot the `$` before the variable: `got` should be `$got`.

Comment: Get rid of the `@` and you would have seen a warning about it.

Comment: Don't use `@` to suppress error messages when you're trying to debug the script. Error message tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: I tried everything, Then I get both the errors "Undefined Variable And Invalid Domain"!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code that uses `$got` inside the `if`. Otherwise you'll try to look up a domain even when the user hasn't submitted the form.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['IP'])){
        $got = $_POST['IP'];
        $ip_look = file_get_contents("https://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?apiKey=at_5DNxXy6d242gzyF26wF2HQlBfwmBM&domainName=".$got."");
        var_dump($ip_look);
    }
}

?>
```